# GeoServer: `org.geotools.process.raster.AffineProcess` could not be instantiated, how to fix?

Tags: geoserver, geotools, tomcat, geoscript, groovy

I have installed GeoServer from OpenGeo Suite 4.1 on a fresh Unbuntu 12.04 following Boundless instructions. Now I wanted to test geoscript-groovy, and installed groovy, geoscript-groovy-1.3.1, geoserver-2.5.2-wps-plugin and geoserver-2.5-SNAPSHOT-groovy-plugin (community, 10-15-2014), with:

```
groovy -v
Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.6.0_32 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux
```

When I restart tomcat 6, I got the following warning about Errors that a class called `org.geotools.process.raster.AffineProcess` cannot be instantiated.

Does anyone know what's the cause of this error, and how to fix it?

> catalina.2014-10-16.log:WARNING: Can't load a service for category
>   "RasterProcess". Cause is "ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.geotools.process.raster.RasterProcess: Provider
>   org.geotools.process.raster.AffineProcess could not be instantiated".
>
> catalina.2014-10-16.log:java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.geotools.process.raster.RasterProcess: Provider
>   org.geotools.process.raster.AffineProcess could not be instantiated
>
> catalina.2014-10-16.log:Caused by:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError catalina.2014-10-16.log:WARNING:
>   Can't load a service for category "RasterProcess". Cause is
>   "ServiceConfigurationError: org.geotools.process.raster.RasterProcess:
>   Provider org.geotools.process.raster.AffineProcess could not be
>   instantiated".
>
> catalina.2014-10-16.log:java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.geotools.process.raster.RasterProcess: Provider
>   org.geotools.process.raster.AffineProcess could not be instantiated
>   catalina.2014-10-16.log:Caused by:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: I guess this is a result of the groovy stuff unless you were getting that issue as soon as you installed GeoServer; it may be worth asking on whatever their community is.